# Is there a way to declare a variable by adding a variable name with a variable value?

Tags: javascript

I have some arrays:

```
var orderObj1 = [], orderObj2  = [], orderObj3 = [], orderObj4 = [], orderObj5 = [], orderObj6= [];
```

And I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(req.user.orders[z])) {
  if (key == orderName[a] + "Name") {
  a + 1;
  var ordName = orderObj + a;
  ordName.push(value);
 }
```

The end goal is `ordName = orderObj1`, and as `a` increases, `ordName` will reference `orderObj2`, `orderObj3` and so on. The value of `a` initially is 0.

Comment: Put all the arrays into another array. An array of arrays. Then `a` becomes an index in this new array that identifies one of the initial arrays.

Comment: `a + 1` is a statement that does not have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in an object

```
var orders = {}
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(req.user.orders[z])) {
    if (key == orderName[a] + "Name") {
    a + 1;
    var ordName = orders["orderObj" + a] = []
    ordName.push(value);
}
```

but native variables, I think you can only get them by using eval and I would not recommend that